# SUM of Column based on Distinct value of other Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Job Work flow table in `SQL Server` which is having the task start_time and end_time on a page and total points for that page.

The Page start_time and end_time on a particular date will be as duplicated i.e the employee will have started and stopped the task on that page so many times like below

My Query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT tu.user_id,tjd.job_id, tjd.job_case_no,isnull(tu.first_name,tu.user_name)Name,(Count(tjw.total_pages)) total_pages,tjd.job_status_id_fk,tjd.drawing_type_id_fk,SUM(tjw.total_points) Points
         FROM dbo.tbl_job_workflow tjw
         LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_user tu ON tu.user_id = tjw.user_id_fk
         LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_job_details tjd ON job_id=job_id_fk
         WHERE isnull(tjd.job_case_no,'')<>'' AND tjw.start_time>='2016-06-28' AND tjw.end_time<='2016-06-28' 
         GROUP BY tjd.job_case_no,tu.first_name,tu.user_name,tu.user_id,tjd.job_id,job_status_id_fk,tjd.drawing_type_id_fk
```

[image]

**Sample Output**

```
user_id job_id  job_case_no        Name total_pages    Points
 4      298 Testcase_17062016_0244PM    Emp1    1        6
 4      346 TestCase-01                 Emp1    2        4
 27     346 TestCase-01                 Emp2    11       11
 27     350 5435435                     Emp2    1        1
 4      350 5435435                     Emp1    5        5
```

In the above Output for case TestCase-01 for uemployee Emp2 the points should be 10 not 11

I need to get Sum of the Points of distinct pages on the for a day.
 i.e if a job with 4 pages haven been worked on with page no 1 having 2 Points have been worked on the same day twice then the Sum of the Points for that day should be 2 not 4

Kindly anyone guide me how to get the Sum based on the above condition

Comment: Requirement not clear... can you explain with some mixed data and sample output?

Comment: so for the rows that you marked what should be the output ? do you mean if job 1 run more than time for the same page... you will ignore one of them ?

Comment: @SufyanJabr Yes the job's page run more than once will be ignored

Comment: @Rajesh In the sample output you are showing: 27/346 /11 /11... means your are not ignoring anything

Comment: Try substituting `Count(tjw.total_pages)` with `Count(DISTINCT tjw.total_pages)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had took the Sum by passing the variables to a function

```
;WITH CTE_Table 
 AS
 (
      SELECT DISTINCT tjw.total_points,tjw.total_pages
      FROM dbo.tbl_job_workflow tjw WHERE USER_id_fk=@user_id and job_id_fk=@job_id
 ) 

 SELECT SUM(total_points) FROM CTE_Table
```